# How to control google ranking of different pages in the same website?

Tags: google-search-console, google-search

This is keyword: `laldupatta mulla`

According to https://www.google.co.in/

**Position 1:**
`https://example.com/smart-kitchen-devices/laldupatta-mulla-one-on-e`

**Position 2:**
`https://example.com/smart-kitchen-devices/laldupatta-mulla-two-tw-o`

**Problem or confusion:**

If you visit 
`https://example.com/smart-kitchen-devices/laldupatta-mulla-one-on-e`

You will get a link referring to
`https://example.com/smart-kitchen-devices/laldupatta-mulla-two-tw-o`

But 
`https://example.com/smart-kitchen-devices/laldupatta-mulla-two-tw-o` is still in second position. So, 
internal link building is not working here.

So my question:
If I want to make the following ranking internally and without external link building, what should I do?

**Position 1:**
`https://example.com/smart-kitchen-devices/laldupatta-mulla-two-tw-o`

**Position 2:**
`https://example.com/smart-kitchen-devices/laldupatta-mulla-one-on-e`

Comment: PR passing through links is not what most people think it is. Authority caps are calculated with link quality values pass a much smaller fraction of authority. The model of a PR 6 page passing PR 3 through two links is not correct. You cannot make one page rank higher than another with a link from the page you want to out rank. You may be able to do this with internal linking if both pages rank near the same. But you can never really know this can you? Another issue you have is SERP link performance. If the one page satisfies more people in the SERPs, there may be nothing you can do.

Comment: Instead, I would focus on making the content stronger for the page you want to appear first in the SERPs. Content influences search results more than people think it does. Push come to shove, link from the home page for a while, make sure there are more internal high quality links to the desired page, make sure that it can be found with fewer clicks from the home page, and lastly, where both links exist on a page - make sure the desired page link appears first.

Comment: Thank you  closetnoc very much. But I think google has made some recent update. So, my previous way of keyword ranking is not working. Previously it worked. For an example, if you search ***   jumble solver ***  you will see engishact.com at within 12 th in google. I performed this with the help of internal link building

Comment: First, keywords do not rank. Please get that out of your head. Pages rank. Search queries return relevent results based upon many factors that hardly include search term matches. Content strength is paramount. Inbound (back) links too. Add to that SERP performance. I want to stress that search engines do not match keywords despite what the SEOs say. It is LSI based. This means content not keywords drive search query results. Also, for what it is worth, I am not sure sculpting works any more, not for the most part. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

At first be sure to use 301 redirects for your first link to destination link.

and then use a link rel canonical tag for the second:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/DESTINATIONURL/" />
```